# Change Text in IFrame without JQuery

Tags: javascript

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#f6d9a54288f17fb68a8b234ec364dc41

I love JQuery, I do, but just for fun I'd like to learn how to write the following in pure/vanilla JS.

```
$("iframe").contents().find("<style>").html(cssEditor.value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
document
    .getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
        .contentDocument
            .getElementsByTagName('style')[0]
                .innerHTML = cssEditor.value;
```

Comment: ok I get it now - http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#f4e40f4d56b8c770cc85f163a1db4912

Answer (score 0):

Use the `contentDocument` property of the `<iframe>` DOM object to get the inner document.

You can then call normal methods on it like `querySelector`.